# Scraping with AJAX - how to obtain the data?

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the data from https://www.anre.ro/ro/info-consumatori/comparator-oferte-tip-de-furnizare-a-gn, which gets its input via Ajax (request URL is https://www.anre.ro/ro/ajax/comparator/get_results_gaz).

However, I can see that the Form Data is in a form of - **tip_client=casnic&modalitate_racordare=sistem_de_distributie&transee_de_consum=b1&tip_pret_unitar=cu_reglementate&id_judet=ALBA&id_siruta=1222&consum_mwh=&pret_furnizare_mwh=&componenta_fixa=&suplimentar_componenta_fixa=&termen_plata=&durata_contractului=&garantii=&frecventa_emitere_factura=&tip_pret=** (if I view source in Chrome). How do I pass this to scrapy or any other module to retrieve the desired webpage?

So far, I have this (is the json format correct considering the Form Data?):

```
class ExSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ExSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['anre.ro']

    def start_requests(self):
        params = {
            "tip_client":"casnic",
            "modalitate_racordare":"sistem_de_distributie",
            "transee_de_consum":"b1",
            "tip_pret_unitar":"cu_reglementate",
            "id_judet":"ALBA",
            "id_siruta":"1222",
            "consum_mwh":"",
            "pret_furnizare_mwh":"",
            "componenta_fixa":"",
            "suplimentar_componenta_fixa":"",
            "termen_plata":"",
            "durata_contractului":"",
            "garantii":"",
            "frecventa_emitere_factura":"",
            "tip_pret":""
        }
        r = scrapy.FormRequest('https://www.anre.ro/ro/ajax/comparator/get_results_gaz', method = "POST",formdata=params)
        print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should produce the required response from that page you wish to grab data from.

```
class ExSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "exspider"

    url = 'https://www.anre.ro/ro/ajax/comparator/get_results_gaz'

    payload = {
        'tip_client': 'casnic',
        'modalitate_racordare': 'sistem_de_distributie',
        'transee_de_consum': 'b2',
        'tip_pret_unitar': 'cu_reglementate',
        'id_judet': 'ALBA',
        'id_siruta': '1222',
        'consum_mwh': '',
        'pret_furnizare_mwh': '',
        'componenta_fixa': '',
        'suplimentar_componenta_fixa': '',
        'termen_plata': '',
        'durata_contractului': '',
        'garantii': '',
        'frecventa_emitere_factura': '',
        'tip_pret': ''
    }

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Referer': 'https://www.anre.ro/ro/info-consumatori/comparator-oferte-tip-de-furnizare-a-gn'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                self.url, 
                formdata=self.payload, 
                headers=self.headers, 
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Care to comment why I need to use exactly payload and specific headers to make it work? Thank you :)

Comment: The variable name `payload` is just a placeholder. It can be any names. if you get rid of the headers, it will still work.